# Build a function that takes a list of strings as input, returns a boolean indicating whether all the strings containing a word

Tags: python, string, list, function

I am write a function that can return Boolean if every string in a list contains the word 'red'.
Below is the code that I came up with, it worked well for test case AllRed(["red hat", "a pair of red shoes", "three red apples"]); and test case AllRed(["red hat", "white shirt", "black eyes"]). However, when I tested it with an empty list, it returned True.

```
def AllRed  (lst):
 return all("red" in i for i in lst)
AllRed([])
```

It is supposed to return false for empty list.

Comment: Check if its empty first then

Comment: Why is it supposed to return false?

Answer (score 0):

The `all()` function is required to return `True` for empty lists. This ensures that the following equivalence will always be true:

```
all(list1) and all(list2) == all(list1 + list2)
```

When `list1` is empty, `list1+list2` is the same as `list2`. So we need `all(list1)` to return `True`.

Similarly, `any()` returns `False` for an empty list, so that

```
any(list1) or any(list2) == any(list1 + list2)
```

is true.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when your iterable (`lst`) is empty, there is nothing to iterate over; and if you see how `all()` works, it returns `True` when iterable is empty.

See [how `all()` works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)